# To find the net uptake would I find the antiderivative of U(t) from t=0 to t=6 or would I find U(6)- U(0)? Why?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbnqx.png)

I found U(t)=[(120.78e^-0.01t)/ (1+5.06e^-0.01t)]

Answer (score 1):

Your function $U(t)$ is the instantaneous *rate* of uptake; it's measured in units of micrograms *per hour*.

During a short (“infinitesimal”) time interval of lenght $dt$ hours, the uptake is $U(t)\,dt$ (which has the units micrograms, since you're multiplying “micrograms/hour” by “hours”).

The total net uptake is obtained by “adding”, i.e., integrating, all these contributions from the initial time to the final time.
So yes, you need to find the antiderivative of $U$.